# A function that convert a number into a vector array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, vector

```
vector<int> initialiser(long long int number)
{
    vector<int> numberArray(20);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = numberArray.begin(); it != numberArray.end(); it++)
    {
        numberArray[*it] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return numberArray;
}
```

when this function is called(eg. initialiser(123456), it returns a zero array instead of an array with this digits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @NathanOliver the issue is on this line numberArray[*it] = number % 10;

Comment: if I put any integer instead of number % 10; it works fine.

Comment: Please edit your question to have [mcve]

Comment: You likely want `*it = number % 10;`

Comment: A detail: `long long` is 64 bit on all platforms I currently know of so using a `vector` of 20 will work for all _positive_ values. In the future, you may however recompile your program on a machine where a `long long` is more than 64 bits. Use `std::int64_t` instead. You know it'll work now and in the future. Also think about what you'd like the result to be if you feed this function a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> vector<int> numberArray(20);
> ```

Initially, the array has 20 zeroes.

> ```
> *it
> ```

This indirects through the iterator. Because all values are 0, this indirection will result in that zero value.

> ```
>  numberArray[*it] = number % 10;
> ```

Here, you modify the the first element of the vector i.e. `numberArray[0]`, because `*it` is zero (see previous paragraph).

In later iterations, you still modify the first element because the value of the pointed element is always zero. In the last iteration the value that you set is zero, because the input integer didn't have 20 digits.

Comment: Op probably wants `*it = number % 10;`  instead

Comment: Or: `for(int& digit : numberArray) { digit = number % 10; ...`